# Why the accusative for „jeden Morgen“?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammar-identification

I am referring to this sentence: „Machst du jeden Morgen ein Omelett mit Käse?“

My grammar is pretty poor, but I think „jeden“ is an adjective and „jeden Morgen“ is an adverb modifying the verb „machst“. Importantly - I hope I‘m right - „Morgen“ is not a direct object. If all this is correct, then what is the grammatical rule that places „jeden Morgen“ in the accusative? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When "jeden" precedes a noun it's called a determiner; when it's by itself it's a pronoun. There are cases where it's declined like an adjective, but it's not used to describe something so it's not an adjective. In the phrase "every morning" you're not saying that the morning is "every". Also, please forget about the phrase "direct object" when it comes to German; it's not really applicable and causes more confusion than enlightenment. What we call a direct object in English can be in the accusative or dative case in German, and which case to use is a function of the verb, not direction.

Comment: "jeden Morgen" is not an adverb. "täglich" (lower case) would be an adverb. The "jeden Morgen" (accusative) just describes the timeframe. Alternatively, you could also use "an" + dative, i.e. "an jedem Morgen".